# ElasticSearch: Is it possible to do a "Weighted Avg Aggregation" weighted by the score?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to perform an avg over a price field (`price.avg`). But I want the best matches of the query to have more impact on the average than the latests, so the avg should be weighted by the calculated score field. This is the aggregation that I'm implementing.

```
{
    "query": {...},
    "size": 100,
    "aggs": {
        "weighted_avg_price": {
            "weighted_avg": {
                "value": {
                    "field": "price.avg"
                },
                "weight": {
                    "script": "_score"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should give me what I want. But instead I receive a null value:

```
{...
    "hits": {...},
    "aggregations": {
        "weighted_avg_price": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing? Is this aggregation query feasible? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug what's available from within the `script`

```
GET prices/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weighted_avg_price": {
      "weighted_avg": {
        "value": {
          "field": "price"
        },
        "weight": {
          "script": "Debug.explain(new ArrayList(params.keySet()))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the following gets spit out

```
[doc, _source, _doc, _fields]
```

None of these contain information about the query `_score` that you're trying to access because aggregations operate in a context separate from the query-level scoring. This means the `weight` value needs to either

- exist in the doc or
- exist in the doc + be [modifiable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-metrics-weight-avg-aggregation.html#_script_2) or
- be a query-time constant (like `42` or `0.1`)

A workaround could be to apply a math function to the retrieved `price` such as

`"script": "Math.pow(doc.price.value, 0.5)"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know about the debug option. I guessed that I only could only use doc values but I couldn't confirm that. Your workaround would work in case the documents scored by price avg, but they are not. A simplification will also work for me: Calculate the aggregation only in the first N results (the N top scored). But I could not achieve this either, I suppose this is also because score is not available at aggregation level.

Comment: That’s right. You can write custom scoring functions in the query and then sort by custom scripts/functions though. From what I understand, you’re more interested in doc-level metrics, not agg-based. Am I right?

Comment: I think no. Because I want the average of a field from all the docs (the price), but calculate it giving more importance to the better results in the query. This should be more realistic /relevant than the regular avg, since the app users more likely will choose on of the top results of the scored query (which is not scored by the price, but other conditions)

Comment: If this score is query-agnostic, you can add a separate `score_weight` field onto the docs and then use that constant in your weighted_avg. I reckon there's no other way around it.

Comment: Noup, it's not, since is the `_score` calculated by the query on query time

Answer (score 0):

@jzzfs I'm trying with the approach of "avg of the first N results (ordered by _score)", using [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                ...
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 0
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "aggs": {
        "top_avg_price": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "price.max"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_hits": {
                "size": 10, // N: Changing the number of results doesn't change the top_avg_price 
                "_source": {
                    "includes": [
                        "price.max"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "explain": "false"
}
```

The avg aggregation is being done over the main results, not the `top_hits` aggregation.
I guess the `top_avg_rpice` should be a subaggregation of `top_hits`. But I think that's not possible ATM.